# How to capture XCTestCase.measure data for TeamCity

Tags: ios, xcode, teamcity, performance-testing, xctest

I'm looking to capture data from XCTestCase.measure and publish it to TeamCity build statistics using service messages. I know how to do the TeamCity integration, but looking at the measure methods, I don't see any way to capture the average or standard deviation.

Here's what is output to the console by my performance tests (I've added newlines for readability):

```
MyFileAbsPath.swift:72: Test Case '-[Tests.DoThingTest testPerformance]' measured 
[Time, seconds] average: 0.096, relative standard deviation: 89.348%, values: 
[0.352850, 0.067076, 0.067139, 0.067347, 0.067608, 0.067030, 0.067298, 0.068089, 0.067496, 0.066790], 
performanceMetricID:com.apple.XCTPerformanceMetric_WallClockTime, 
baselineName: "", baselineAverage: , maxPercentRegression: 10.000%, 
maxPercentRelativeStandardDeviation: 10.000%, maxRegression: 0.100, maxStandardDeviation: 0.100
```

It's occurred to me to append `| tee` to my build command, then write a program to capture that data using regex, but that's a really ugly solution to me and I'd rather not do it.